# Discord.py - unable to get members of a channel

Tags: python, discord.py

```
print(message.guild.member_count)  # 7
print(len(message.guild.members)) # 1
for member in message.guild.members:
    print(str(member))  # the bot itself
```

I'm trying to get members of a Discord channel, but it only lists the bot itself. It used to work, I didn't change the code at all, but it suddenly doesn't. I gave the bot admin permissions, don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to get all the members of your server or just a single channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 2 things that utilize the [Intents Data Class](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#intents) and your code will work as expected.

1. Update the developer portal to enable member actions for your bot.

[image]

2. Add the following code to your bot:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = Bot(command_prefix=list(PREFIX), intents=intents)
```

Please see [Where'd my members go documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#where-d-my-members-go).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the count and names of all members in your guild, use [guild.fetch_members()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.fetch_members).

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = client.get_guild(123456789)
    member_count = guild.member_count
    print(f"Total member count: {member_count}")
    async for member in guild.fetch_members(limit=150):
        print(member.name)
```

Also be sure you setup your intents as @DaveStSomeWhere said above.